A server action library is not defined when calling it from client component
I'm new to NextJs world and I've been struggling with this issue for a while now, so basically I'm trying to implement a logout action using Lucia which simply do a small db check then clears out cookies, this action should get called from the ui and this is a snippet of my component
'use client';
...
export default function LayoutPage({ children } : { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const handleLogout = async () => {
    await logoutAction();
  };

  return (
    ...
    <li className="w-6 cursor-pointer">
      <form action={handleLogout}>
        <button type="submit">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faRightFromBracket} />
        </button>
      </form>
    </li>
    ...
  );
}

when I try to run this I get this following error
ReferenceError: dns is not defined


I somehow understand the issue, as a client component is blind when it comes to server libraries which is in this case dns but I couldn't find a solution for it, I tried several examples from the internet like using useCalback hooks and such but none of them worked
I would really appreciate any suggestion or tip!
Thanks in advance!

is your logOutAction a server action and did you mark it with 'use server' ?
It's best practice to make your pages server components and create a client component for your form.

well yeah my logOutAction is a server action, I will try making my page a server component to and try to abstract out the client component from it and see how it goes, thanks for the tip!
